# Validation error w3.org: background-image and image-set (retina resolutions)

Tags: html, css, validation, background-image, retina-display

The following lines of code are the background images on a small website with a full screen header image. I wanted to apply the styles directly in the html with the intention, that loading of the images is not blocked by css-parsing.

I tried two different approaches:

```
<div class="..." style="background-image: url('assets/img/textatelier/textatelier_elisabeth_zenz_header_3733.jpg'); background-image: -webkit-image-set('assets/img/textatelier/textatelier_elisabeth_zenz_header_1867.jpg' 1x, 'assets/img/textatelier/textatelier_elisabeth_zenz_header_3733.jpg' 2x);background-image: image-set('assets/img/textatelier/textatelier_elisabeth_zenz_header_1867.jpg' 1x, 'assets/img/textatelier/textatelier_elisabeth_zenz_header_3733.jpg' 2x);" data-zanim-xs='{"delay":0,"animation":"zoom-out"}' data-zanim-trigger="scroll">
```

The second approach the same, except also encapsulating the image paths with url().

Both do not validate on [validator.w3.org](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Felisabethzenz.at%2F) (remark: this is the link to the validation of the website, which is live for you to see). I would deeply appreciate any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the MDN documentation for `image-set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-set).

The only specification that describes it is *CSS Images Module Level 4* which is currently a working draft.

It isn't standard yet, so it is invalid, so the validator reports it as invalid.